# Solidity warning to use receive function

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.8.x

Why is solidity giving me this warning???[image]
Do we need to declare receive function everytime??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare the `fallback() external payable` function, then it means that you are intending to receive ether directly, as any other EOA (Externally Owned Account). So, Solidity recommends you to also add a `receive() external payable` function.

As you may know, the `receive` function is executed when ether was sent directly to the contract (without specifying any function) and no data was provided. `fallback` is executed when ether was sent directly to the contract without specifying any function and data was provided, or if the EVM does not recognize a function selector in the data, or the `receive` function was not declared.

For this reason, if you are intending to receive ether directly, add the `receive` function, and add the `fallback` function too but to handle incoming data (usually accessible through `msg.data`).

Actually, you could also use another syntax for the `fallback` function to explicitly receive data:

```js
fallback(bytes calldata input) external payable returns(bytes memory output) {}
```

The `receive` function does not support this overload.

So yes, it's not mandatory but is recommended that if you add one of those functions, add the other.

Comment: So, is it just a better way to write contracts? And it won't cause any serious bug or problem later???